# Alterar campo de float para decimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, float, decimal

Eu tenho um campo, que na model foi como `float`, e foi como ficou salvo, e já tem dados nessas colunas.
Porém o que acontece, é que agora eu preciso de 6 casas decimais após a vírgula. Exemplo: 10,023568

Porém com o `float` isso não é possível, ou até então não consegui descobrir nenhuma maneira de fazer isso.

Eu pensei em alterar de `float` para `decimal`, porém quando eu gero o arquivo para alteração:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<decimal>(
            name: "ValorTotalPedido",
            table: "PedidoFornecedor",
            type: "decimal(10,6)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(float));

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<decimal>(
            name: "ValorProdutos",
            table: "PedidoFornecedor",
            type: "decimal(10,6)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(float));
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<float>(
            name: "ValorTotalPedido",
            table: "PedidoFornecedor",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(decimal),
            oldType: "decimal(10,6)");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<float>(
            name: "ValorProdutos",
            table: "PedidoFornecedor",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(decimal),
            oldType: "decimal(10,6)");
    }
```

Porém quando vou realizar o `update-database` ele me retorna **Erro de estouro aritmético ao converter real no tipo de dados numeric.**

Tentei mudar apenas minha `ViewModel`, porém mesmo assim salva com apenas duas casas 10,02.

Na minha `Model` o campo está assim `public float ValorTotalPedido { get; set; }`

Tentei colocar assim na `ViewModel` `public decimal ValorTotalPedido { get; set; }`

Comment: Ja tentou utilizar parseFloat para converter inteiro para real

Comment: @luizgustavo ja sim, e não resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Tenta criar uma coluna auxiliar com o tipo decimal, transferi todo valor nele, e depois faça delete do campo do tipo float, salva a atualização, depois podes criar o campo com o tipo decimal e fazer a transferência do campo auxiliar para ele, e faça delete no campo auxiliar.

Answer (score 0):

A aceitação de alterações da estrutura DDL do banco de dados pelo migration vai depender muito do banco de dados. Se não me engano, estruturalmente campos *float* são maiores que *double* e essa alteração não é permitida.

O recomentado nesse caso é você manipular seu migration para:

1 - Criar um novo campo double temporário no banco de dados;

2 - Updatar convertendo o campo atual para este campo novo;

3 - Remover o campo antigo;

4 - Renomear o campo temporário para o nome antigo (essa possibilidade também depende do banco de dados, caso não funcione, considere criar o campo com o nome do antigo e updatar de volta a informação).

As migrações que fiz que me exigiu processos dessa forma, e faz sentido considerando a integridade da informação pelo banco de dados.

Espero ter ajudado. Abraço.